# Tlib.exe (Borland / Embarcadero) doesn't handle paths properly that contain hifen-minus symbols, what can I do?

Tags: static-libraries, c++builder, command-line-interface

When I try to execute something similar to this line below:

> tlib.exe /C mylib.lib
>   +-obj\Release\lib-10\src\object\objectFile.obj

I get this output:

> TLIB 6.2 Copyright (c) 1987-2010 Embarcadero Technologies, Inc.
>   Warning: '.\obj\Release\objectFile.obj' not found in library

If I remove the "lib-10" manually and put the objectFile.obj at the "obj\Release\src\object\" dir it works fine.

What can I do?

At the [website](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/TLIB.EXE,_the_Library_Manager) there are no useful information about this. **If there is no workaroud I will try this manual solution. Just to clarify: tlib.exe is my only choice.**

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried putting double quotes around the path?

Comment: I'd suspect that because the options allow `+-`, that the `lib-` being interpreted as `lib` `-`, which is logical. The other thing I notice is that your error says "not found in library"; `+-` means to `update module in library`, and if the module isn't there to update it could cause this error. Are you sure you added it first before trying to update it? (I got this from running `tlib` from a command prompt with no parameters and viewing the syntax on the screen.)

Comment: @HansPassant Yes, same behavior.

Comment: @KenWhite, Yes, with other libs that doesn't have the hifen-minus symbol works. Maybe you are right, tlib.exe tries to interpret this symbol as "delete module".

Comment: @HansPassant Same behavior at PowerShell, but with "cmd" works properly.

Comment: minor nit, Tlib is the librarian, not the linker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recent versions of Tlib will handle properly quoted paths with -/+ on the command line, but older versions do not. If the IDE or your shell isn't properly quoting these paths, your best bet is to use a different path.
I would discourage use of paths containing those characters. I know it's a remnant of times past, but many console applications grew out of those legacy times and still have the old constraints.